# Populating formcontol with multiple values

Tags: angular, class, model, form-control

I have a form that has multiple select dropdowns created from info obtained from an API.

Not sure if I am doing this correctly, but I am able to populate the form for the get with the appointmentPackages property.

```
export class AppointmentsPackagesFormComponent implements OnInit {

  packageTypeList: Observable<APSPackages[]>;


  constructor(
    public formbulider: FormBuilder,
  ) { }


 ngOnInit(): void {

this.apsApptForm = this.formbulider.group({

  appointmentPackages: []

});

this.getPackageTypes();

}

  getPackageTypes() {
    this.packageTypeList = this.apsService.getPackageTypes();
  }


}
```

Here is what the template code Looks like

```
        <form [formGroup]="apsApptForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(apsApptForm.value)">
            <div class="row full-name-inputs">
              <div *ngFor="let package of packageTypeList | async" class="col-md-6 input-group">

                <label>{{package.packageType}}</label>
                <select fullWidth class="form-control" name="{{trimming_fn(package.packageType)}}" style="width:100%;">
                  <option value="">Select A Package</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let p of package.packages" [value]="p.packageId">{{p.packageName}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>

          </div>
```

the package List from the API is structured in this way.

```
[
  {
    {
      "packageType": "Test Package",
      "packages": [

        {
          "packageId": 309,
          "packageType": "test Package",
          "packageName": "Rust and Undercoat (JLGL/JRSL)",
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "packageId": 310,
          "packageType": "test Package",
          "packageName": "Undercoat only (JQCL)",
          "active": true
        }
        ]

      },

    {
      "packageType": "Test Package2",
      "packages": [

        {
          "packageId": 309,
          "packageType": "test Package2",
          "packageName": "Rust and Undercoat",
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "packageId": 310,
          "packageType": "test Package2",
          "packageName": "Underbody wash",
          "active": true
        }
        ]
      },


    {
      "packageType": "Test Package3",
      "packages": [

        {
          "packageId": 34,
          "packageType": "test Package3",
          "packageName": "Rust and Undercoat (JLGL/JRSL)",
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "packageId": 31,
          "packageType": "test Package3",
          "packageName": "fake package Name",
          "active": true
        }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

On the submit I want to be able to  set all of the selected values into an array that can be a POST call to the API via httpClient. However I am only able to get one value from the selects group.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provide more info, I am able to only give you steps.
Hope its helpful.

1. First you require to add each packageTypeList items to appointmentPackages FormGroup.
2. With that your all dynamic control will be available in your form.
3. Then you can point to each formControl and get values or directly get values from form.